# How to get the value of the item of list Template in sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have used a list as below.

```json
xtype: 'list',
layout: 'fit',
activeItem: 0,
store: {
    fields:['imageUrl','name','status'],
    data: [{
        imageUrl: 'arrow.png',
        name:'IMG23',
        status:'p'
    }, {
        imageUrl: 'arrow2.png',
        name: 'IMG20',
        status: 'P'
    }]
},
```

Now I want to store the value of imageUrl in a variable. 
I am using `var URL = {imageUrl[0]};`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the variable `store` references your store, you can do this

```
variable URL = store.getAt(0).get('imageUrl')
```

Look at the manual :
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.data.Store#method-getAt